# How to Load Form inside of Bootstrap Modal Box

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to load **upload.php** inside of bootstrap modal box, here is my code

```html
  <h4>Update Database</h4>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</div>
 </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Step One 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
   <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="drop">
   Update DB
    <button>Upload</button> 
   </div>
   <ul>
          </ul>
   </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But when I click on upload button, the page will redirect to **upload.php**

> How can I load it inside of modal box after click on upload button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if that works, but try using Ajax requests.

Comment: How to do ajax request based on my code?